How to get sharp edge with particles
This is my current output:
Torus with crooked edges
As you can see, the edges are “blocky”.
This is already using round particles through discarding pixels in the Points material custom fragment shader:
float distanceToCenter = length(gl_PointCoord - 0.5);
if (distanceToCenter > 0.5)
    discard;

This is the expected result:
Torus with smooth edges
Crisp edges when the particles are in their original position (distanceToOrigin < 0.001)
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance guys!

Like Nephelococcygia wrote, pixel ratio and antialiasing will fix your issue. Because you have points I would set depthwrite:false as well. https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/pen/eYaWppR

What you want to achieve is called antialiasing.
To succeed you can operate on two axes.
The first one is to update the Renderer:

By enabling the default antialias, that uses MSAA;
By upgrading the pixelRatio (high-consuming).

The second one is to update your fragmentShader code:

Implementing signed distance field known as SDF (example here).


Hey Nephelococcygia sorry for the late response!

So, I tried a bunch of AA methods I could find (MSAA, SMAA, FXAA) and used them as a postprocess pass, but none of them were able to correct the jagged edges sufficiently, I even tried tweakin their code to sample more neighbouring texels and still no good.
Then I guess there's only SDFs left... Though I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to achieve AA with that since I'm using a Points mesh that has no exact shape/edge defined
